# Storage account connectivity method for AKS

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-aks

I'm setting up a Storage Account so I can [Dynamically create and use a persistent volume with Azure Files in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-dynamic-pv). Doing this to:

1. Have a PV and PVC for the database
2. A place to store the application files

AKS does create a storage account in the `MC_<resource-group>_<aks-name>_<region>` resource group that is automatically created. However, that storage account is destroyed if the node size/VM is changed (not node count), so it shouldn't be used since you'll lose your files and database if you need a node size/VM with more resources.

This documentation, nor any other I've really come across, says what the best practice is for the Connectivity method:

- Public endpoint (all networks)
- Public endpoint (selected networks)
- Private endpoint

The first option sounds like a bad idea.

The second option allows me to select a virtual network, and there are two choices:

1. `MC_<resource-group>_<aks-name>_<region>`... again, doesn't seem like a good idea because if the node size/VM is changed, the connection will be broke.
2. `aks-vnet-<number>`... not sure what this is, but looks like it is part of the previous resource group so will also be destroyed in the previously mentioned scenario.

The third option contains a number of options some of which are included the second option.

So how should I securely set this up for AKS to share files with the application and persist database files?

**EDIT**

Looking at the both the "Firewalls and virtual networks" and "Private endpoint connections" for the storage account that comes with the AKS node, it looks like it is just setup for "All networks"... so maybe having that were my actual PV and PVC will be stored isn't such an issue...? Could use some clarity on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure where the problem lies. all the assets generated by AKS are tied to AKS lifecycle. if you delete AKS it will delete the `MC_*` resource group (and that it 100% right). Not sure what do you mean about storage account being destroyed, it wouldn't get destroyed unless you remove the pvc and set the delete action to reclaim.

Reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-dynamic-pv

As for the networking part, selected networks with selecting the AKS nodes network should be the way to go. you can figure that network out by looking at the AKS nodes or the AKS agent pool definition(s). I dont think this is configurable only using kubernetes primitives, so that would be a manual\scripted action after storage account is created.

Comment: Second point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#why-are-two-resource-groups-created-with-aks. I was just merely stating you shouldn't use the storage account that is created in `MC_*` if you really want to persist your data.Last I heard AKS doesn't support upgrading the node size/VM (not to be mistaken with node count). You need to upgrade and then migrate to it. Thus, you shouldn't keep your PV/PVC in the `MC_*` resource group because "it will delete the `MC_*` resource group (and that is 100% right)."

Comment: right, and you can do that, i believe that is possible: https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/873

Comment: Oh ok, I guess I assumed that, that was best practice. Didn't realize Microsoft was intending for people to use the storage account in `MC_*`. They should be more clear about that in their documentation. I interpreted it as: "Sure, there is a storage account in this resource group, BUT if you delete your k8s VM, it is going to get deleted too, so you probably don't want to use it if every intend to upgrade to a new VM... or something." At any rate, thanks for the feedback though and how to secure the end point better than just the default "All Networks".

Comment: nothing is going to get deleted if you delete the vm, if you remove the aks resource than yes. for upgrading node size you can use multiple node pools. you can upgrade the default node, but all the secondary ones are upgradeable (delete\create). I'm not sure you read the link I've provided. you can use another resource group for those resources. read the link